# How to set value of a hidden field with name as an array in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, hidden-field

This is the hidden field I have: `<input type="hidden" value="" name="name[]">`

I tried this jQuery: `$(input[type=hidden]).val('0');` and it seems to work fine.

I'd like to know if I can use:

1) a combination of both `input[type=hidden]` and `input[name=name]` in a single query

OR

2) just use something like `$(input[name=name]).val('0');`?

Both the above don't seem to work. Is it because name[] is an array?

Comment: actually, according to http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-cdata ` ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").` But i suppose some browsers support the  [ ] . That's odd...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it but you as the name contains brackets, you have to do something like that:

```
$('input[type=hidden]')
// Or
$('input[name="name[]"]')
// Or
$('input[type=hidden][name="name[]"]')
```

These 3 selectors are actually working.

Answer (score 1):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/naveendalmeida/cgJkr/

```
$('input[name="' + name + '[]"]').each(function() {

    $(this).val('Some value');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
 $(input[name="name[]"]).val('0');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write it this way

```
$("input[type='hidden'][name='name[]']").val('hello');
```

Hope it heps

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
$('input[type="hidden"][name*="name"]').val('0');
```

This checks for every `input` that has type **equals** to `hidden` and input that has name **contains** `name` in the value.

```
$('input[type=hidden][name="name[]"]')
```

This checks for every `input` that has type **equals** to `hidden` and input that has name **equals** `name[]` in the value.

You can do any combination you want for more information look at jquery
Multiple Attribute Selector API doc
http://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/

[See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SDAbC/)

Comment: that will probably result in unpredictable behavior IMO

Comment: I think, `[name^="name"]` better than `[name*="name"]`.